# How can I make window read frame size from its contentView automatically and fix it size from contentView?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am using a main swift file for launching my app like this:

```
import Cocoa

// **** Main **** //
let nsApplication: NSApplication = NSApplication.shared
let appDelegate: AppDelegate = AppDelegate()
nsApplication.delegate = appDelegate
nsApplication.run()
```

And then I am doing this:

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    private let window: NSWindow = NSWindow()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        window.styleMask = [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView]
        window.backingType = .buffered
        
        window.title = "No Storyboard Window"

        let myView: MyView = MyView()
        window.contentView = myView
        
        // This 3 line of code should not be needed, because myView already has frame forn initialization!
        // window.setFrame(myView.frame, display: true)
        // window.maxSize = myView.frame.size
        // window.minSize = myView.frame.size
        
        
        
        window.center()
        
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        
    }
    
}


class MyView: NSView {
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500)))
        self.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500))
        self.wantsLayer = true
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

As you can see in my custom NSView class I already set the frame size, but when I create an instance of it and setting it as `window.contentView` window is unable to set own frame coming from myView, my goal is that window set its frame automatically from its contentView and not be able to became bigger or even smaller. I do not want either set maxSize or minSize for window, and I want window be able to automatically update own frame when it receive own contentView something like SwiftUI modifier called `.windowResizability(.contentSize)`